# will xrdp logout of the currently logged in account?

Tags: xrdp

I have a ubuntu desktop running some scripts that I would like to have remote access to from windows.

I'm using xrdp and it seems fairly straightforward. But, my concern is that if I remote into the ubuntu desktop it would log out of the system and thus stop the scripts I'm running.

Will this be the case? I will be using the same login account

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are running xrdp you will be basically connecting through a new session to your remote system.  If you logout from the xrdp session, you will be killing the xrdp session and not the one you might have open on the ubuntu locally.

You can perform a basic test and check indeed that you are connecting to two different  and separate sessions.

Hope this help 
See ya